# ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column - when inserting into CLOB

Tags: sql, oracle, nhibernate, oracle11g

I am inserting a large string into a `CLOB` column. The string is (in this instance) 3190 characters long - but can be much larger.

The string consists of xml data - sometimes the data will commit, sometimes i get the error. The error occurs roughly 50% of the time.

Even string which contain over 5000 characters will sometimes commit with no problem.

Unsure where to go next as i am under the impression that `CLOB` is the best data type for this data.

I have tried `LONG` `LONG RAW`

Someone suggested using `XMLTYPE` however that does not exist in my version of Oracle (11g - 11.2.0.2.0)

**My insert statement**:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE(InterfaceId, SourceSystem, Description, Type, Status, StatusNotes, MessageData, CreatedDate, ChangedDate, Id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

MessageData is the `CLOB` column where the error is occuring, i have tried commiting without this data populated and it works.

**Error**

```
ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
```

Comment: Oracle versions 3.1?  I'm pretty sure version 3 was available in 1983.  Is that really the version?

Comment: I went on help > about and that's what is says. Also says copywright Oracle 2005-2011.Its oracle sql developer if that helps

Comment: try select * from v$version;

Comment: ah right - Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Don't use longs or long raws, they are deprecated since many years (not to say since quite a long time ;-)

Comment: @wolφi Yep you answered my other question hah, but no I'm, using `CLOB` now, it sorted my other problem - but another has arisen

Comment: Sorry, didn't want to become a LONG nuisance ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE 
ADD COLUMN XML_COL XMLTYPE;
```

AND THEN

```
SQL> INSERT INTO MYTABLE(..., XML_COL) VALUES  (..., XMLTYPE('<root>example</root>'));
```

The key is to use XMLTYPE column and then use XMLTYPE() function to convert your string to XMLTYPE.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm using nHibernate and unsure of how to alter the `INSERT` statement in this way. Surely using `CLOB` should work, as the data is just a really long string...

Comment: XMLType is indeed the appropriate datatype to store XML. If you're unsure about hibernate, let's address that separately.